# Why doesn't the pattern or required attribute work?

Tags: html

I am currently doing homework, and following the instructions the book gives me, but I can't get the required or pattern tags to work. I am creating a survey form, and trying to make an error come up when the user doesn't type in their name, receipt number, or email. Here is a portion of it.

```
<label for"receipt">Receipt number *</label>
<input name="receipt" id="receipt" 
    placeholder="re-nnnnnn"
    required="required"
    pattern="^re\-\d{6}$" />
```

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: Specifically the pattern. I can type in any information I want in the reciept number and it will accept it.

Comment: Just to clarify, I am using notepad++. It is not accepting the pattern attribute at all, it is just staying black as if it were text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things i see

- the `required` attribute does not need a value, the existence of the attribute is what makes it required or not.
- the `-` does not need to be escaped so use `^re-\d{6}$` for the pattern attribute
- the issue with the notepad++ is that the language formatting/color-coding is not up-to-date with all the attributes.

```html
<input name="receipt" id="receipt" 
              placeholder="re-nnnnnn"
              required pattern="^re-\d{6}$" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked! This book is a little confusing, and isn't always right :/

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to write like that u can just write : required and it will work
and whats your pattern i don't catch that

Comment: I think this should be comment not an answer.